# what does positive class mean in classification tree, in R?

Tags: r, tree

So I'm a newbie in data science, and have some question regarding tree model.

 Below is the result of my classification modeling, but I'm having trouble intrepreting it.
[image]
As you can see at the very bottom line in the bottom-left part of the screen, it says 'positive class : 1'. Our target attribute has value of either 1 or 0. What does that 'positive class : 1' mean in this case?

 I very much appreciate your help. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

`Positive Class: 1` indicates that the positive class, i.e. the class which you are most interested in, is labeled as `1` in your dataset; it is *not* the numerical value R uses under the `levels` of the factor, but the value with which it is encoded/written in the dataset.

For more information about it, you can see the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/caret/versions/6.0-86/topics/confusionMatrix) of `confusionMatrix` function from `caret`, which I believe is the one you used. Look for the optional argument named `positive`.

Answer (score -1):

Positive class is the class that is related to your objective function. For example, if you want to classify whether the objects are present or not in a given scenario. So for all the data samples where objects are present will be considered in the positive class. So in your problem, you want to identify in which case you will have 1 as a target variable so it is considered as a positive class.